# Verify Woocommerce web hook in Laravel

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, woocommerce, webhooks

I'm trying to verify data coming in, via a request from a Woocommerce web hook that is responsible for updating product items in my Laravel database.

I've created a Middleware called VerifyWoocommerce, which fires correct, as I can see in my logs.

I'm a little uncertain as to how I can verify that the incoming request actually came from Woocommerce.

Here's my VerifyWoocommerce.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Request;
use Log;

class VerifyWoocommerce
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $signature = Request::header('x-wc-webhook-signature');
        $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, env('WOOCOMMERCE_WEBHOOK_ITEM_UPDATED'), true));

        Log::debug($signature);
        Log::debug($calculated_hmac);


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Both variables return different values. Am I comparing the correct values?

**UPDATE**

Here's an output of the body that Woocommerce is sending

```js
[2017-08-01 15:12:34] local.DEBUG: array (
  'id' => 38,
  'name' => 'Long Sleeve Tee',
  'slug' => 'long-sleeve-tee',
  'permalink' => 'http://velvetcake.local/product/long-sleeve-tee/',
  'date_created' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
  'date_created_gmt' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
  'date_modified' => '2017-08-01T15:12:33',
  'date_modified_gmt' => '2017-08-01T15:12:33',
  'type' => 'simple',
  'status' => 'publish',
  'featured' => false,
  'catalog_visibility' => 'visible',
  'description' => '<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>',
  'short_description' => NULL,
  'sku' => NULL,
  'price' => '25',
  'regular_price' => '25',
  'sale_price' => NULL,
  'date_on_sale_from' => NULL,
  'date_on_sale_from_gmt' => NULL,
  'date_on_sale_to' => NULL,
  'date_on_sale_to_gmt' => NULL,
  'price_html' => '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#82;</span>21.93</span>',
  'on_sale' => false,
  'purchasable' => true,
  'total_sales' => 0,
  'virtual' => false,
  'downloadable' => false,
  'downloads' => 
  array (
  ),
  'download_limit' => -1,
  'download_expiry' => -1,
  'external_url' => NULL,
  'button_text' => NULL,
  'tax_status' => 'taxable',
  'tax_class' => NULL,
  'manage_stock' => false,
  'stock_quantity' => NULL,
  'in_stock' => true,
  'backorders' => 'no',
  'backorders_allowed' => false,
  'backordered' => false,
  'sold_individually' => false,
  'weight' => NULL,
  'dimensions' => 
  array (
    'length' => NULL,
    'width' => NULL,
    'height' => NULL,
  ),
  'shipping_required' => true,
  'shipping_taxable' => true,
  'shipping_class' => NULL,
  'shipping_class_id' => 0,
  'reviews_allowed' => true,
  'average_rating' => '0.00',
  'rating_count' => 0,
  'related_ids' => 
  array (
    0 => 40,
    1 => 39,
    2 => 41,
  ),
  'upsell_ids' => 
  array (
  ),
  'cross_sell_ids' => 
  array (
  ),
  'parent_id' => 0,
  'purchase_note' => NULL,
  'categories' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 18,
      'name' => 'Tshirts',
      'slug' => 'tshirts',
    ),
  ),
  'tags' => 
  array (
  ),
  'images' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 19,
      'date_created' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'date_created_gmt' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'date_modified' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'date_modified_gmt' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'src' => 'http://velvetcake.local/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/long-sleeve-tee.jpg',
      'name' => 'Long Sleeve Tee',
      'alt' => NULL,
      'position' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  'attributes' => 
  array (
  ),
  'default_attributes' => 
  array (
  ),
  'variations' => 
  array (
  ),
  'grouped_products' => 
  array (
  ),
  'menu_order' => 0,
  'meta_data' => 
  array (
  ),
)  
[2017-08-01 15:15:05] local.DEBUG: array (
  'id' => 37,
  'name' => 'Hoodie',
  'slug' => 'hoodie',
  'permalink' => 'http://velvetcake.local/product/hoodie/',
  'date_created' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
  'date_created_gmt' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
  'date_modified' => '2017-08-01T15:15:04',
  'date_modified_gmt' => '2017-08-01T15:15:04',
  'type' => 'simple',
  'status' => 'publish',
  'featured' => true,
  'catalog_visibility' => 'visible',
  'description' => '<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>',
  'short_description' => NULL,
  'sku' => NULL,
  'price' => '42',
  'regular_price' => '45',
  'sale_price' => '42',
  'date_on_sale_from' => NULL,
  'date_on_sale_from_gmt' => NULL,
  'date_on_sale_to' => NULL,
  'date_on_sale_to_gmt' => NULL,
  'price_html' => '<del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#82;</span>39.47</span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#82;</span>36.84</span></ins>',
  'on_sale' => true,
  'purchasable' => true,
  'total_sales' => 1,
  'virtual' => false,
  'downloadable' => false,
  'downloads' => 
  array (
  ),
  'download_limit' => -1,
  'download_expiry' => -1,
  'external_url' => NULL,
  'button_text' => NULL,
  'tax_status' => 'taxable',
  'tax_class' => NULL,
  'manage_stock' => false,
  'stock_quantity' => NULL,
  'in_stock' => true,
  'backorders' => 'no',
  'backorders_allowed' => false,
  'backordered' => false,
  'sold_individually' => false,
  'weight' => NULL,
  'dimensions' => 
  array (
    'length' => NULL,
    'width' => NULL,
    'height' => NULL,
  ),
  'shipping_required' => true,
  'shipping_taxable' => true,
  'shipping_class' => NULL,
  'shipping_class_id' => 0,
  'reviews_allowed' => true,
  'average_rating' => '0.00',
  'rating_count' => 0,
  'related_ids' => 
  array (
    0 => 35,
    1 => 34,
    2 => 36,
  ),
  'upsell_ids' => 
  array (
  ),
  'cross_sell_ids' => 
  array (
  ),
  'parent_id' => 0,
  'purchase_note' => NULL,
  'categories' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 17,
      'name' => 'Hoodies',
      'slug' => 'hoodies',
    ),
  ),
  'tags' => 
  array (
  ),
  'images' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 18,
      'date_created' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'date_created_gmt' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'date_modified' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'date_modified_gmt' => '2017-07-31T07:45:31',
      'src' => 'http://velvetcake.local/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hoodie.jpg',
      'name' => 'Hoodie',
      'alt' => NULL,
      'position' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  'attributes' => 
  array (
  ),
  'default_attributes' => 
  array (
  ),
  'variations' => 
  array (
  ),
  'grouped_products' => 
  array (
  ),
  'menu_order' => 0,
  'meta_data' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Comment: Take a looke [here](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) and see if it can help you !

Comment: @Maraboc is this not for sending requests TO Woocommerce? I'm receiving data FROM woocommerce in Laravel via a webhook.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen  Check my answer below. You pretty much have match the HMAC Sent in the Header requested to a calculated one, if they match you proceed to the next request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my eventual solution

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $signature = Request::header('x-wc-webhook-signature');

    $payload = Request::getContent();
    $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, env('WOOCOMMERCE_WEBHOOK_ITEM_UPDATED'), true));

    if($signature != $calculated_hmac) {
        return false;
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

The second parameter of the hash_hmac function needed the request body as a string, which I got from Request::getContent()

Answer (score 0):

You're actually quite close to getting this right. I'll give you a high level overview/pseudocode of what needs to happen (or I'll just end up writing the code, see below).

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
    // Get the HMAC value from request/header from the Woocommerce request, whatever the hmac value you want is called
    $hmac = $request->get('hmac');

    // Get the signature - your secret
    $signature = Request::header('x-wc-webhook-signature');

    /* Get the woocommerce URL
    * They should give you a code or some kind of ID and also a TIMESTAMP (this is important in your HMAC Calculation) in the request
    * You'd need to figure out this bit
    */
    $woocommerceData = $request->get('woocomerceData');

    // Calculate the HMAC
    $calculatedHmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $woocommerceData, $secret, true);

    // encode the calculated HMAC
    $calculatedHmac = base64_encode($calculatedHmac)

    // Check if the HMAC and Calculated HMAC Match, if they do continue
    if ($hmac == $calculatedHmac) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    // If they don't stop processing
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Giolliano. I'm battling to find the Timestamp/URL as well as the HMAC value from the Woocommerce request. Am I looking in the wrong place? I've added an update in my original post of the request from Woocommerce.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen So have a look here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/woocommerce-webhook-log.png at the woocommerce documentation. See how they have the `wc-webhook-signature` + the `arg` in the content. Try and calculate the HMAC with that data and use the date/time of the post request.